# Using usbip on raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have been trying to use usbip on my raspberry for hours now.
after `apt-get install usbip` no module gets created:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo modprobe usbip
FATAL: Module usbip not found.
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo modprobe usbip-host
FATAL: Module usbip-host not found.
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

There's no error message when installing, so at the moment, I have no idea, how I should continue.

[One of the howtos I tried.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4433/how-do-i-make-my-raspberry-pi-act-as-a-wireless-usb-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is still relevant but I successfully use **VirtualHere** for the same purpose in a similar setup.

It doesn't require kernel compilation and is free for up to one USB connection per server. See installation instructions [here](http://virtualhere.com/usb_server_software). I'm accessing it from Windows 7 clients with their (free and quite simple) client software and it works like a charm.